# FUTURE GRANTs on tables without MANAGE GRANTs access

Tags: permissions, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sql-grant

In Snowflake, is it possible for a user to make FUTURE GRANTs on tables/schemas if their role doesn't have the MANAGE GRANTs role?  From [here](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/grant-privilege.html#future-grants-on-database-or-schema-objects), it seems like no, but I want to make sure I'm not missing anything.

For context: my team has several pipelines that do full replaces of tables (i.e., drops the old table and swaps the new table in). I'm in a larger organization and our head DBA is hesitant to give my team's role the MANAGE GRANT permission.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm miss understanding, but it sounds like you need the same grants on future tables as those you currently have on existing tables, which is exactly how issuing future grants works.

For example if you need ALL PRIVILEGES (except ownership) on all tables and future tables in a schema, you should have your DBA execute the following:

***For existing tables:***

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA DB1.SCHEMA1 TO MY_ROLE;`

***For future tables:***

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON FUTURE TABLES IN SCHEMA DB1.SCHEMA1 TO MY_ROLE;`

As tables are created or dropped and re-created, you and your team will always maintain those same privileges.  This will eliminate any repetitive work for your DBA and will assure that you always have access to your tables the moment they are created.

Answer (score 0):

Giving FUTURE GRANTs requires running a `GRANT` statement, which requires MANAGE GRANTs.

From that documentation page:

> The MANAGE GRANTS global privilege is required to grant or revoke
>   privileges on future objects at the database level. By default, only
>   the SECURITYADMIN and ACCOUNTADMIN roles have the MANAGE GRANTS
>   privilege.

Comment: As a workaround perhaps the DBA could create a stored procedure (executed with owner's rights i.e. the DBA privileges which includes manage grants) which executes future grants for your team - on specific pipelines (could be passed in as params). This way manage grants could be locked down but the appropriate granting done as initiated by your team: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html#label-owners-rights-stored-procedures